# How to cache only for the back button

Tags: php, caching

Can someone explain to me how to set a cache for my page that if the user hits the back button and is offline or something then he will still see the previous page like on SO and most sites.

But how can i force that when a new HTTP request is sent, it will fetch a new one since the content changes by the minute (ie a forum)?

Thanks

Comment: You can't control whether the client sends a new request or not (even for the back button).

Comment: If you use caching headers it will cache the page till you click the refresh button of force a refresh with new headers.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if you hit a new page of Stackoverflow do you not get the latest version (or at least not later then 30 seconds.) So how are they making a cache which lasts when not even connected to the internet?

Comment: @Repox: See my question to lawrence

Comment: [Caching tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) - here's clear explanation how http caching works and how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally discovered that for some reason putting a cache on all my pages,
will let them have a back button forever, however when the page is refreshed, it will still fetch a new one from the server.

Wierd, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really do this is to inform the client browser that it can cache the webpage, which will (sometimes) prevent the browser from sending another HTTP Request if the cache time has not expired (see here for more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache#Cache_control).

However, if the content of the page is dynamic and continuously refreshing (as you seem to imply if it is a forum). Then you probably don't want to allow the browser to cache at all.

Comment: then how can you press the back button when online on Stackoverflow?